# ElasticSearch: Query to get result only when all dates of a nested data less then present date

Tags: elasticsearch

> Mapping:

```
{"mappings": {
"supply": {
  "properties": {
    "rotation_list": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "project_end_date": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "end_date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
          }
        },
        "total_days": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

> Below is the data

```
{"rotation_list": [
{
  "project_end_date": [
    {
      "end_date": "2020-07-07"
    },
    {
      "end_date": "2020-08-07"
    }
  ],
  "total_days": 25
},
{
  "project_end_date": [
    {
      "end_date": "2020-08-07"
    }
  ],
  "total_days": 26
}]}
```

> query

```
{"query": {
"bool": {
  "filter": [
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": "rotation_list.project_end_date",
        "query": {
          "range": {
            "rotation_list.project_end_date.end_date": {
              "lt": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}}}
```

I just want to get the result, if only all the end_date of project_end_date section less then now. so in this example there are two project_end_date. project_end_date1 has two end date and project_end_date2 has 1 end date. So it should check base on the project_end_date section end date. Can any one help me on this.

If you see the below section:

```
"project_end_date": [
    {
      "end_date": "2020-07-07"
    },
    {
      "end_date": "2020-08-07"
    }
  ]
```

If i am comparing today date("2020-07-08") with the above date. One of the above date is not less then today date.So, It shouldn't give the result.

Comment: Which is project end date section?

Comment: "project_end_date": [
    {
      "end_date": "2020-07-07"
    },
    {
      "end_date": "2020-08-07"

Comment: @Gibbs. Can you know this how to solve.

Comment: Are you ok to change the mapping?

Comment: @Gibbs yes i am ok with it

Comment: Why are you not considering the second `project end date` object in `rotation list`?

Comment: I am considering the both. So the scenario over here is to check the end date by group. In the first project end date there are two end date. Both should be less the present date. Then only it should come as a match.

Comment: So you always want to check where more than one end date is present? Is it?

Comment: Not like that. If no matter how many dates are there in a project end date section. All date should be less then present date. 
Let's say there are two project section.
section one have two dates which are 2020-aug-01 and 2020-july-01.
section2 have only one date which is 2020-aug-08.
So basically no matter how many date are part of project end date, all should be less then present data. so as per my concern i should not get the result.